# PivotTable grouping and counting

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable (Screenshot 1) which classifies the row labels and classifications.

[image: Classifcation]

There is a field I want to add from the PivotTable field list called `date(u.created_at)` as an extra column in PivotTable which should sum up the number of users added in a particular time period.

Screenshot - 2 (How I want results to be displayed):

[image]

Currently, if I put that field as values it goes date by date and makes the table very big. All I want is to sum up the new users joined which should sum up types of classification as well as all dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your data: make seperate values of your classifications.

Your data wouls have these fields: country, schools, number of educators, number of students and your date field